# Configuration Apache2

Tags: debian

the first thanks for your help, my question is:

in the file /etc/apache2/site-enabled I have the configuration of my site, https//example.com on server 1.

I want to change the configuration so that the URL https://example.com/file points to another server 2 with the private ip address (x.x.x.x.x.x).
please can you tell me how I can change the configuration to get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you may want to use [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html).

To enable `mod_proxy`in Debian, use:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
```

In addition, you will also likely want to enable `mod_proxy_http` and `mod_proxy_html`:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_html
```

Under your `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` configuration, add the following to your virtual host for `https//example.com`:

```
ProxyPass /file http://x.x.x.x
ProxyPassReverse /file http://x.x.x.x
```

Don't forget to restart Apache after saving all your changes:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: To enable [mod_proxy_http](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_http.html) 
(and automatically [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html)), use `a2enmod proxy_http` as root. This creates symlinks from `/etc/apache2/mods-available/` to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/` including `*.load` files with the `LoadModule` directives (you don't need to add them to your config).

Comment: Appreciate the corrections and clarifications. =)